# On namespace 'names': ::std:: vs std::

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, namespace-organisation

I have been looking over some posts here on Stackoverflow, and I have noticed that most people use `std::` but some people uses `::std::`

I think i have read something about a *global scope* or something like that in namespaces as a reason to use `::std::` (but i can't find it now, because it was in a comment to an unrelated question)

Is there any reason to prefer one way versus the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bad idea to write code like this, but you *could*:

```
namespace foo {
    namespace std {
        int bar;
    }
    std::string s;
}
```

In that case, the `std::string` refers to the `::foo::std` namespace, not the `::std` namespace. So, using `::std::string` is just being a little bit more unambiguously careful.

Comment: So, for general purposes, std:: would be the one to uses, right?

Comment: Usually, yes, I would use `std::` and not `::std::`.