# Is using nested std and posix namespaces undefined?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, language-lawyer

According to the (now defunct) StackOverflow documentation on [Extending the `std` namespace](http://www.riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/17171/extending-the--std--or--posix--namespace) and [[namespace.constraints]](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.constraints):

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to a namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified.

and

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace `posix` or to a namespace within namespace `posix` unless otherwise specified. The namespace `posix` is reserved for use by ISO/IEC 9945 and other POSIX standards.

Do these rules only apply to the **global** `std` and `posix` namespaces, or is something the following also undefined:

```
namespace HelloWorld {
    namespace std {
        void terminate();
    }
}
```

Perhaps it's because I'm native in English, but the wording of those rules seems to be a bit vague in this aspect.

Comment: The rule only apply to the top-level namespaces. But using a namespace named e.g. `std` inside another namespace will be confusing for the people reading or maintaining your code (which might include you in the future). Think about what happens if you do `using namespace HelloWorld` (with the example above).

Comment: Not really, it's not extending `std` since it's done in a different namespace. And it will also cause massive problems doing something like that. While there is no rule forbidding the use of the name `std` inside another namespace (that I know of) it's not something you should do, or even consider doing.

Comment: Also related: [On namespace 'names': ::std:: vs std::](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18544651/3919155).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's indeed a somewhat obscure rule of English. You see that the rules talk about  **a** namespace within namespace `std`. Why aren't we talking about "a namespace `std`" or "the namespace `std`"? It's because `std` is the (unique) name of that namespace. Compare "a president", "the president", "president Trump".

So yes, `namespace std` uniquely refers to that top-level namespace.